# Cannot create grails projects in STS but from command line

Tags: grails

I have recently started to work with grails. I was able to create applications and generate stuff. Yesterday I wanted to resume my work, after a little break and ran into the following error, when trying to create a new project:

```
Command terminated with an exception:    
org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails process died
(see details for partial output)
Grails process died
------System.out:-----------

------System.err:-----------
```

This error only occurs when I use the SpringSourceTool, if I try using the command line it works fine. My first reaction was to change the java version from 1.8 to 1.7, but that didn't help. My environment variables look like this (I am running Fedora Linux 19)

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.0.x86_64
GRAILS_HOME=/home/peer/grails/grails-2.3.0
```

They are also included in the PATH variable.

Can anybody help? Thanks, Peer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in STS:

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3277

A work-around is provided in the link.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it did resolve the first error, but I got a new one. The output is as follows:

startup failed:
/target/work/plugins/database-migration-1.3.5/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/databasemigration/DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.

Any idea?

Comment: I was able to fix my problems after I did what you advised but I had to do something more. First I downgraded to Java 1.7, but I am not sure if this was necessary.

I than took a look at the "Problems" window (Window -> Show View -> Others -> General -> Problems) and googled for the displayed errors. I found out that using Grails 2.3.0 with STS is not working well and switched back to Grails 2.2.3 and GGTS 3.3.0, which is working now.
I also disabled checking for mismatches between compiler levels (Window -> Preferences -> Groovy -> Compiler).

Anyhow thanks for your help!
Peer

Comment: I installed Grails 2.3.6 with JDK 1.8 and did nothing more than running create-app and then run-app. This produced the error described above.

The solution was to downgrade to JDK 1.7. Then it runs normally.

Cheers,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

For anyone pulling their hair out trying to create a grails project using the STS extension for Grails, here is my setup and following is what I did to get it working:

-- OSX 10.8.4 Build 12E3067 --
-- STS Version 3.4.0 --
-- Grails 2.3.3 (installed separately to STS) --

1. Fresh installed STS 3.4.0
2. I **de**selected the Preferences/Groovy/Compiler/Enable checking for mismatches between
   project and workspace Groovy compiler levels
3. I **ONLY** selected the Grails Support option when installing the extensions (nothing else)
4. Restart STS 3.4.0 (i.e. restart eclipse)
5. I then pointed my Grails project to my existing Grails 2.3.3 installation
6. Make sure that the environment variable GRAILS_HOME is set and exported in the same
   shell from which you invoke STS otherwise you will get a process termination error in
   Eclipse (STS)

This worked.